# R split a number into single digits

Tags: r, split

I have a data frame:

```
V1=c("A","B","C")
V2=c(2,3,5)
a<-cbind(V1, V2)
```

[image]

I would like to split every row into single rows according to number in the column V2:

[image]

Could You please help me?

Thank You in advance.
Inna

Comment: `data.frame(V1=rep(a[,1], a[,2]), V2=1)`

Comment: `a <- data.frame(V1, V2)` and `tidyr::uncount(a, V2) %>% mutate(V2 = 1)`

Comment: @jogo `?rep` ... times: *other inputs being coerced to an integer or double vector*.